# Is it necessary to use "The" on product name "The Last Words"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, titles

EDIT:
The company that I work is developing a game and we are deciding the best name of the game. The final one was "Last Words" but we were not sure if we have to use the "The Last Words" or just "Last Words".

The doubt is:
Is using just "Last Words" grammatically incorrect? Do you guys see any problem of using only "Last Words"?

Without "the" seems cleaner and simpler.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: I'd like to closevote on the grounds that ELU doesn't do "assistance with product names", but I've reached my daily limit.

Comment: "The last word" can be used to describe the finest example of something ("the last word in fashionable wallpaper"), or is the final statement about something (my sister always has the last word in an argument). "Last words" (plural) is usually used for the last thing someone says before they die. Are you sure you want to use this phrase?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You can name a product anything you like; it can feature unusual uses, bozo colocations, unorthodox orthography, nonce words, nonsense words; it can even take something else's name, if it's in a different class of goods or services. Whether or not to include *the* depends on the product and what you are trying to convey with the name, and we won't be able to give you a definitive answer according to our rules and format. Even Facebook began as *The Facebook*, but [then changed suddenly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEgk2v6KntY).

Comment: Are you naming a new product of your own? Are you branding a new consumer product for someone else?

Comment: It's the name of a new game, so a product to someone else. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @MARGANA I didn't know about this "dying" meaning =( maybe I'll change. The idea was related to the last words spoken about something during the game and now you need to find out what happened. Thanks for helping

Comment: No, it can also mean something different, as in "He had the last word", in which it means he had the closing remark, the final comment or statement in an argument.

Comment: @Catija Not this game, a new one.

Comment: [This one](http://store.steampowered.com/app/355530/)? Also does not include the article... do you get my gist? Find an official page about the game and see what the creators of the game did... if "the" is part of the official game title, use it... otherwise, do not.

Comment: @Sankarane ... _it can also mean something different, as in "He had the last word", in which it means he had the closing remark, the final comment or statement in an argument._ Indeed; see my earlier comment, but also note what happens when it's plural.

Comment: @ MARGANAOh, yes. We've all heard, "Those were his last words". Good point. Thanks.

Comment: There's already a game called "last words". Creating a new game with the same title is not really a good idea... unless that steam game I linked to a minute ago is the game you're talking about.

Comment: @Catija It's not this one. Probably I'll have to change =(

Comment: Very nice edit and a stellar first impression. Again, welcome. I'll be watching you! :-) (most likely from a distance, but I'm fickle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Last Words" sounds okay. Mispronounced by a non-Anglophone, it may get passed along as "Lost Words".

Try saying "The End" as opposed to "End". "The Last Words" has the same appeal to me, as the former.

Comment: Or "last rights", but I am bothered by how a brand new user has been treated here. The downvote to this answer isn't mine. I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: @Jolenealaska I got a little bored at first, but also found some great people looking to help! Thanks

Comment: @Danielzt  That is very good to hear. I don't come to this Stack often, and what I perceive as rudeness is a big part of the reason why. So I'll say it, even though this isn't "home". Welcome.

Comment: @Danielzt: In my opinion, a product name needs no grammar, but it needs to have some appeal and be catchy; hence my answer. And by the way, hang on. Ask more questions. We can all learn. A great hangout, this!